# Remove rectangular border around matplotlib basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

Is there a way to plot a basemap map without the border around the plot? I am using this code:

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
    ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.add_geometries(poly, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), facecolor='none', edgecolor='0.75', linewidth=2.)

    map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=llcrnrlon, llcrnrlat=llcrnrlat, urcrnrlon=urcrnrlon, urcrnrlat=urcrnrlat,
                  resolution='h', projection='cyl')

    # draw parallels.
    parallels = np.arange(-90., 90, 5.)
    map.drawparallels(parallels, labels=[1, 0, 0, 0], fontsize=12)
    # draw meridians
    meridians = np.arange(-180., 180., 5.)
    map.drawmeridians(meridians, labels=[0, 0, 0, 1], fontsize=12)
```

and the map looks like this (I want to keep the country boundary but not the black rectangular border):

[image]

Comment: Does `ax.axis("off")` work?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, it does not, I called it right before saving the figure

Comment: Wait... are you mixing basemap and cartopy here? Could you provide a [mcve] please?

Comment: For Cartopy, use `ax.outline_patch.set_visible(False)`